# CloudFormation deploying implicit AWS::APIGateway::Deployment even after explicitly defining one

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

Trying to deploy a simple HelloWorld API using CloudFormation/SAM.
I have to defined an `AWS::Serverless::Api`, `AWS::ApiGateway::Resource`, `AWS::ApiGateway::Method` and a `AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment`. But during `sam deploy` I see that another `AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment` is implicitly created, one that is deployed **before** the API Method.

The API related resources deployed:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Operation                                       LogicalResourceId                               ResourceType                                    Replacement                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ Add                                           HelloWorldAPIDeployment5332c373d4               AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment                     N/A                                           
+ Add                                           HelloWorldAPIDeployment                         AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment                     N/A                                           
+ Add                                           HelloWorldAPIMethod                             AWS::ApiGateway::Method                         N/A                                           
+ Add                                           HelloWorldAPIResource                           AWS::ApiGateway::Resource                       N/A                                           
+ Add                                           HelloWorldAPIStage                              AWS::ApiGateway::Stage                          N/A                                           
+ Add                                           HelloWorldAPI                                   AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi                        N/A
```

How can I stop the implicit `AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment`(`HelloWorldAPIDeployment5332c373d4`) from being created?
It causes the following error:

```
CREATE_FAILED                                   AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment                     HelloWorldAPIDeployment5332c373d4               Resource handler returned message: "The REST  
                                                                                                                                                API doesn't contain any methods (Service:     
                                                                                                                                                ApiGateway, Status Code: 400, Request ID:     
                                                                                                                                                02f3dcab-0126-4d16-8c19-27fb1e05c381,         
                                                                                                                                                Extended Request ID: null)" (RequestToken:    
                                                                                                                                                d75d527f-da4f-78a5-3000-be3e156ccc7a,         
                                                                                                                                                HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

Here's the relevant template code:

```
HelloWorldAPI:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties: 
      Name: HelloWorldApi
      StageName: !Ref StageName

  HelloWorldAPIResource:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref HelloWorldAPI
      ParentId: !GetAtt HelloWorldAPI.RootResourceId
      PathPart: hello

  HelloWorldAPIMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      HttpMethod: GET
      ResourceId: !Ref HelloWorldAPIResource
      RestApiId: !Ref HelloWorldAPI
      Integration:
        Type: AWS_PROXY
        IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
        Uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${HelloWorldFunction.Arn}/invocations
          # - Arn: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn

  HelloWorldAPIDeployment:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref HelloWorldAPI
      StageName: !Ref StageName
    DependsOn:
      - HelloWorldAPIMethod
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't switch that off. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-generated-resources-api.html):

> When an AWS::Serverless::Api is specified, AWS Serverless Application Model (AWS SAM) **always generates** an AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi base AWS CloudFormation resource. In addition, it also always generates an AWS::ApiGateway::Stage and an AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment resource.

If you want to keep using `AWS::Serverless::Api` you have to use the auto-generated `AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment`, rather then your own. You do this by appending `.Deployment` to the name:

```
!Ref <api‑LogicalId>.Deployment
```

Alternatively, don't use `AWS::Serverless::Api` at all, as you seem you are creating everything from scratch anyway.

Comment: Append `.Deployment` to which name?

Comment: No, I meant which resource should refer to `HelloWorldAPI.Deployment`? Because that deployment is being deployed before all the other API resources are.